# ORA-00911: Invalid Character via ODBC, Adhoc SQL - within comments?

Tags: oracle11g

When executing the following statement (as an example) I get an error `ORA-00911: Invalid character`

```
"/* it is the end of the world */\nSELECT 1 FROM MyTable;"
```

Other comments are fine. What's the problem?

We use comments to annotate our Ad-Hoc SQL.

(Oracle11gR2, Windows )

This does not happen via SQL Plus or SQL Developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a comment includes the whole word `end` then the Oracle driver (or server) appears to be interpreting this badly.
If you remove the `end` word within the comment, the statement executes correctly.

I think this is because it doesn't expect a semi-colon after experiencing an 'end' directive (even though it shouldn't be parsing a comment).

The following statement executes without issue and returns 7.

```
/* end */\nSELECT 7 FROM MyTable
```

The following statement raises ORA-00911

```
/* end */\nSELECT 6 FROM MyTable;
```

The following statement returns 5

```
/**/\nSELECT 5 FROM MyTable;
```

It's likely that Oracle parses the comment because that's how it applies join operation/optimization 'hints'.